# imacros. Need to extrapolate random values from one column

Tags: csv, scripting, firefox-addon, imacros, extrapolation

I have an imacros script that takes data from a csv file. But i need to tell imacros to take data randomly from a column. i.e.:

```
=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
```

in column 2 I store a lot of values, but I need for each line it takes a different value from COL2.
is it possible?

---

Reply to Bestmacros.

Thx Bestmacros but I guess I'm still doing something wrong cause it doesn't work. So this is the script:

```
SET !VAR0 901
ADD !VAR0 {{!LOOP}}
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ; 
SET !DATASOURCE file.csv
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:post_three CONTENT=http://www.{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:source ATTR=ID:htmlSource CONTENT={{!VAR0}}&#160;<a<SP>href="http://www.{{!COL3}}"<SP>target="_blank">www.{{!COL4}}</a>
```

As you can see I need the random value from col2 in 5 tags. The other columns must have only one value.
Where do I insert your code considering that this whole script must be repeated many times (in loop) and for each time VAR0 must be increased by 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - here is example which will take random data from first 10 lines (from column 2)

```
SET !VAR0 901
ADD !VAR0 {{!LOOP}}
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ; 
SET !DATASOURCE file.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:post_three CONTENT=http://www.{{!COL1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```

Comment: thx but what if i already set datasoource_line with loop because I need it for other stuff?
    
     SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

Comment: so set it again after taking random value from col1

Comment: updated my answer - you must understand how it work from example.

Comment: thank you very much! I think I understood it. As soon as I get 15 reputation and can vote I'll vote your answer.

Comment: @hugester.com now you have 15 reputation :) . if this answer worked, you also need to click the hidden V check bellow the number of votes. this way you will mark it as the right answer for your question.